# вывод массива в одну строку

Tags: java

Есть массив типа String 
нужно вывести значения массива в одну строку через запятую 
Пример:

молоко, мясо, хлеб

как это можно сделать?
Пытался с System.out.println(res.replaceAll () но не понимаю как убрать []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String[] strArray = { "молоко", "мясо", "хлеб" };
    System.out.println(String.join(", ", strArray));
```

Comment: спасибо. Не видел такой метод)

Comment: @AmoRa Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода print(x,+" ,")

Comment: тогда будет лишняя запятая в конце