# метод, который возвращает предыдущий результат

Tags: java

Есть класс **Operation** c 2  методами.

**int calculate(int a, int b)** 
и
**int returnPrevious()** - возвращает предыдущий вычисленный результат. 
Необходимо создать наследника (Addition) и переопределить соответственно методы.
**Не понятно как переопределить метод, который возвращает предыдущий результат**

```
abstract class Operation {
    abstract int calculate(int leftOperand,int rightOperand);
    abstract int returnPrevious();


}

public class Addition extends Operation {


    @Override
    int calculate(int a, int b) {
        int result;
        return result= a+b;

    }

    @Override
    int returnPrevious() {
        int prevresult=
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081804/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Addition extends Operation {

    int last;
    int beforeLast;

    @Override
    int calculate(int a, int b) {
        beforeLast = last;
        last = a + b;
        return last;
    }

    @Override
    int returnPrevious() {
        return beforeLast;
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение это супер, но хотелось бы понять как работает метод. Не могли бы поподробнее описать его работу. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: @AmoRa Нет уж. Сначала Вы скажите, что Вам непонятно.

Comment: оО непонятен beforeLast = last; как он влияет на дальнейший код

Comment: @AmoRa Он влияет на дальнейший код так, что в члене класса `beforeLast` сохраняется значение предыдущего вычисления.